# how to show all the methods to a particular class, or functions such as **kwargs?

Tags: python, methods, keyword-argument

i tried help(**kwargs), and help(kwargs) but received an error.

There are online sites that show you all available methods for a dictionary, but none for something not so newbie friendly like kwargs.

I am asking for a generic method to find built in python info so that I don't have to ask those questions online. Thanks.

Edit_1, for example, I saw this from someone else's code:

```
def somefunction(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.item():
        print key, value
```

How do I find out more methods like the above example, item() ?

Comment: `kwargs` isn't a function. Can you show your code?

Comment: If you just want to know what methods a dict has, `help(dict)` ought to work. Different dicts don't have different methods unless you start using subclasses like `Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**kwargs** is just a name and ** is use to unpack dictionaries (kew words argument )

**NB: kwargs could be any name you like**

Little bit about kwargs:

```
>>> def foo(**new_kwargs):
...     print new_kwargs
...
>>> dic = { 'key' : 'value' }    
>>> foo(**dic)
{'key': 'value'}
>>>
>>> foo(key='value')
{'key': 'value'}
>>>
>>> foo(dic)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
>>>
```

And :

If you want to see all the attributes and method for a particular object (even class is an object in python): Use `dir built-in function`:

```
dir(...)
    dir([object]) -> list of strings
```

And if you want to see any particular attributes is method or function, you can use `callable` to check if they are callable:

```
>>> dir(dict)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__',
 '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__',    
 '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items',
 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault',    
 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
>>>

>>> callable(dict.keys)
True
>>>   


>>> class foo(object):
...     class_variable = 'Some String'
...     def function():
...         return 'Some String'
...
>>> dir(foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__',     '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
'__weakref__', 'class_variable', 'function']
>>>
>>> callable(foo.class_variable)
False
>>> callable(foo.function)
True
>>>
```

What ever you show extra in dir(foo) are from base class `object`.

Comment: this answer is actually helpful for newbies like myself. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`*kwargs` just means that a method takes *multiple keyword arguments that aren't defined*.

Take this example:

```
def foo(a,b,c=10,**kwargs):
    pass
```

This method has two required *positional* arguments, one argument `c` that is optional (since it has a default value), and then takes *any number of additional arguments*. All these are valid calls:

```
foo(1,2,hello='world',bar='baz')
foo(1,2,3,hello='world',bar='baz',zoo='foo')
```

Since they are variable, there is nowhere to list them.

The best you can do is use the built-in [`help()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) function and hope that the programmer has written some [`docstrings`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to highlight the use of the function you are interested in:

```
def foo(a,b,c=10,**kwargs):
    '''This function takes extra arguments
       that can be used to calculate the
       meaning of life. The first two arguments
       a and b are required, c is set to 10 as
       a default.

       Examples:
           foo(1,2,hal='are you there?')'''
```

Now, when you do `help(foo)` it will print out that string.

[`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) is another built-in that is useful. It returns a list of *attributes* for the passed in object, or a list of *names* (variables) that are available in the current scope.

If you want to know what all things you can do with an object (basically, what goes after the `.`), type `dir(theobject)`. For example, `dir({})` will list all the attributes of a dictionary.

Comment: actually, help(dict) solved my question, but I will give you a raise anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for documentation of builtin module,this link might help: http://effbot.org/librarybook/builtin.htm. Your question is not specific, it would be great if you add more details.